# iOS System Icons not respecting UIButton's UIImageInsets

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uiedgeinsets

I am using iOS's [system icons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/) so that I can have a consistent user interface throughout my project. One thing that I've noticed when using these icons is that, even if I set a system icon as the image for a `UIButton`, it will not grow to fill the size of the button, like normal project images do. For example, if we have a very large `UIButton`, let's say a height and width of 500, even if the `UIButton`'s image insets's left, top, bottom, and right values are each set to 0 in the interface builder, the system icon being used for the button's image will remain its same small size.
[image]
[image]

In fact, the only time that the system icons will respect the interface builder's instructions for image insets is when said insets require that the image make itself smaller.

[image]

Does anybody know how to make system icons behave similarly to normal project images with respect to `UIButton`s' image insets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: check the marks in the picture]
you can use interface builder. In the attributes inspector on the right-hand side, use the Control section as follows:

and code you can use in storyboard also as you are already using.

Comment: This is actually the best answer, as it allows me to fix my issue from the interface builder (though it seems both methods work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it was an `UIImageView` when you set it's `contentMode` as "Aspect Fit", system image would size itself to conform height and width.

[image]

The problem is you can't set `UIButton.imageView`'s `contentMode` on storyboard but you can do it programmatically,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    yourButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    yourButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
}
```

Comment: Ah duh, I had tried setting the content mode from interface builder, but I suppose that was the content mode for the UIButton itself, not its UIImageView. Thanks!